# ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: errors, pdftex, texworks

I am doing an empirical work on STATA and I used the command sutex in order to obtain the LaTeX code for summary statistics tables.
I am just copying and pasting it on TeXworks (pdfLaTeX file) as said in the help page of the command but I obtain this error:

[image: error]

I am pretty dummy with LaTeX language so maybe the error is something stupid. The command lines are these:

[image: command lines]

Comment: provided nothing has been excluded from the example as shown, the error message `missing \begin{document}` is correct.  you need to insert that line somewhere after `\documentclass{report}` and before `\begin{table}`.

Comment: After \documentclass{report} you should have \begin{document} and at the end you should have \end{document}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message "Missing \begin{document}" means that you are missing a `\begin{document}` to begin your document. Google could have told you that, by the way. Please refer to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure for more information.

Comment: Thank you all of you guys. And sorry but my mind's gone blank, I'm working from this morning in front of the pc and I did not well interpret the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tb]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
a & 1\\
b & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{My nice table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```